# JavaFX built with netbeans on my 64 bit Mac won't run on 32 bit Linux

Tags: java, cross-platform, javafx-2

I'm a little perplexed. I have a JavaFX program I'm working on (hobby) and it builds and runs just fine on my Mac. (I have the latest Oracle Java 7). When I run the jar file that was built on the Mac (in the latest NetBeans), on my 32-bit Linux system (also with the latest Oracle version) it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
file:/home/me/aFolder/SomeOne/Saved/Something.jar!/Something/mainWindow.fxml
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2186)
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2028)
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2744)
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2709)
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2696)
   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
   at Something.Something.start(Something.java:33)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
   at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
   at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
   at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The line for Something.java:33 is where I call

```
AnchorPane mainWindowPane =     
  (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(UdoMail.class.getResource("mainWindow.fxml"));
```

So, I'm rather confused as to where to start. This is a jar file built on my Mac, moved to a 32-bit Linux (running the latest 32 bit Oracle Java), and ran.

What's rather strange is that if I build this on the 32-bit Linux, then run the Linux built jar file on my Mac, I get (effectively) the same error on the Mac.

If I run on the same platform as I build, everything works just fine. (That is, if I take the code and build it on Linux it runs perfectly on Linux, but not on Mac.)

Since I can't seem to run a debugger on Linux for the Mac built jar file (and vice versa), I'm a little lost as to where to start looking. I've already ensured I'm using File.separator and looked for other OS specific stuff, but I'd like to find out what these lines in FXMLLoader.java are (in the source code) to see why it's barfing. After commenting out most of the code, the line that seems to cause the barf is a simple File instantiation:

```
File myFile = new File(userDirectoryString);
```

I use many files and directories, and this line is the first call for file or directory usage in my code. I've validated the String "userDirectoryString" and it's correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can help only with the notion, that you are here :

```
public static final String INITIALIZE_METHOD_NAME = "initialize";

// Initialize the controller
            Method initializeMethod =   getControllerMethods().get(INITIALIZE_METHOD_NAME);

            if (initializeMethod != null) {
                try {
                    MethodUtil.invoke(initializeMethod, controller, new Object [] {});
                } catch (IllegalAccessException exception) {
                    // TODO Throw when Initializable is deprecated/removed
                    // throw new LoadException(exception);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException exception) {
                    throw new LoadException(exception);
                }
            }
```

You can find this code in OpenJFX.

We can see, that this means, that method initialize() has thrown an exception, during its work..

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the code on the system it's supposed to run on. The JVM scans your system and writes byte code for the machine you built it on. There's nothing wrong with your code, it's how the JVM works.